# Using a Perl variable as the substitute expression

Tags: perl, substitution

I want to read the substitute expressions flexibly from external data,
so my problem could be reduced to the following:

```
my $pattern = "s/a/b/g";
my $string  = "abcd";

$string =~ $pattern;
print("$string\n");
```

This is not functioning, but where is my problem?
Or does it even have no solution?

Comment: You probably need to look at the `qr//` operator for quoting regular expressions.  However, you would normally use `my $qr1 = qr/$pattern/; while (<>) { s/$qr1/$replace/g; print; }` or similar — separating the pattern from the replacement text.  There's also `eval`, but it is dangerous.

Comment: Of course more complex expressions are planned like: s/(a)(b)/$2$1/g

With the qr() I already played, luckless.

Comment: Yes, of course.  The `qr//` operator may be a key part of the answer, though — for the match part.  The replacement part is trickier; in fact, you may be forced to use `eval` with that. (Casual experimentation with `s///e` or `s///ee` didn't produce the result I wanted. In the replacement is complex, then it's likely you'll need `eval`.

Comment: I tried: `my $pattern = 'ab(.*)fg';
my $replace = 'AB$1$1FG';

while (<>)
{
    print "In:", $_;
    my $line = $_;
    eval "s/$pattern/$replace/g";
    print "O1:", $_;
    $line =~ s/ab(.*)fg/AB$1$1FG/g;
    print "O2:", $line;
}` — given the input `abcdefg`, it produced three lines of output: `In:abcdefg` — `O1:ABcdecdeFG` — `O2:ABcdecdeFG`, as desired.  You could read the whole `s///` expression from a file and `eval` it.  Note the security risks with `eval`; it isn't "safe".

Comment: Many thanks Jonathan, I guess I'll go the way of separating the pattern, thought of keeping the expression at once.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Re "*you may be forced to use eval with that.*", That's what String::Substitution is for.

Comment: @ikegami: OK — if you say so.  I've not heard of String::Substitution, so I couldn't recommend it.  It's the sort of reason I used comments, not an answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I wasn't implying that you were hiding its existence. I just figured you'd want to know there was a solution and what it was.

Answer (score 2):

`$pattern` doesn't contain a regex pattern; it contains a bit of Perl source code. To evaluate Perl code, you need [`eval EXPR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) (or `do` or `require`).

Requiring Perl code from a user is a bad idea, though. Instead, I recommend the requiring the pattern and the replacement separately, as in the following:

```
my $pattern = 'a';
my $replacement = 'b';
my $string = 'abcd';

$string =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/g;
```

Use a function from [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution) if you want to allow `$1` and such to be allowed in the replacement expression.

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

my $pattern = '(a)(b)';
my $replacement = '$2$1';
my $string = 'abcd';

gsub_modify($string, $pattern, $replacement);
```